# If Excel file is open, show messagebox and end form

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I have a setup, where multiple users input data in a form (the "input" workbook), that copies the data to another workbook (the "data" workbook). I get an error, if two users are trying to update data simultaniously. The "data" workbook stays open, thus blocking the update option from other users.

I want to get a message box saying: "Workbook in use, please try again", whereafter the "data" workbook closes and the user send the data from the form again, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Could somebody please give me some pointers on how to solve this?

Here is the code from the input form from the "input" workbook:

```
Private Sub CmdButton_add_Click()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("G:\afregsyd\KSC SYD\Salgsregistrering\indtastninger2.xlsx")
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Ark1")

'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.TextBox_Initialer.Value) = "" Then
Me.TextBox_Initialer.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please complete the form"
Exit Sub
End If

'copy the data to the database
ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Date
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_Initialer.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox_Salg.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox_Liv.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox_Bank.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox_Mersalg.Value

'close Workbook
ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=True

MsgBox "Data tilføjet", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Data tilføjet"
'clear the data
Me.TextBox_Salg.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_Liv.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_Bank.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_Mersalg.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_Initialer.SetFocus
End Sub



Private Sub Cmdbutton_close_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Review/Share Workbook/Editing/ check "Allow changes by more than one user at the same time."

For manipulations using VBA, please, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153058

code from the link:

```
Sub Example1()

  ' Test to see if the Read-only attribute was assigned to the file.

  If GetAttr("c:\test.xls") And vbReadOnly Then
    MsgBox "File is Read-only"
  Else
    MsgBox "File is not read-only"
  End If

End Sub
```